# iphone SDK: how to add a new line char to my uitextview programmatically?

Tags: iphone, newline, uitextview

Please help me adding a line break (\r\n) programatically to my `UITextView`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you get the text from the text view, create a mutable version of the text, then add just \n, the set the text view's text, it'll work. Don't put a carriage return and a linefeed both.

Comment: Amazing, new line created. Thanks a lot for your kindness Lucius. You are helping me the second time today itself. :)